# creates excel but doesn't draw the chart, phpexcel and codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I have a big problem, I need create a excel with a chart, but when execute the function, creates excel but doesn't draw the chart.

the function is

```
function excel_get(){
      $this->load->library('Classes/PHPExcel');
      $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Nombre de la hoja');

      $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
        array(
          array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
          array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
          array('Q2',   56,   73,     86),
          array('Q3',   52,   61,     69),
          array('Q4',   30,   32,     0)
        )
      );

      $dataseriesLabels = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1),
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1),
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1', NULL, 1)
      );

      $xAxisTickValues = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4)
      );

      $dataSeriesValues = array(
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$5', NULL, 4),
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
        new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$5', NULL, 4)
      );

      $series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
        PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,      
        PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,  
        range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),        
        $dataseriesLabels,                          
        $xAxisTickValues,                              
        $dataSeriesValues                         
      );

      $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

      $plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));

      $legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL,false);
      $title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
      $yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value qwerty');

      //Create the chart
      $chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
        'chart1',          
        $title,            
        $legend,          
        $plotarea,          
        true,          
        0,            
        NULL,          
        $yAxisLabel      
      );

      $this->phpexcel->getActiveSheet()->addChart($chart);

      $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($this->phpexcel);
      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
      header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="newFile.xls"');
      header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

      $writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
      $writer->save('php://output');
    }
```

**PD:** the table is generated correctly.

Help me please, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Charts are only available with the `Excel2007` Reader/Writer for OfficeOpenXML (.xlsx) format files

Comment: I change to .xlsx but is same

PD: my code is this..... 
      $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($this->phpexcel);
      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
      $writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
      $writer->save('php://output');

Answer (score 0):

I am Sorry, I just discovered that always work, but the chart is very very very very small in the corner top-left and I dont saw it.

Now my problem is show the graph with a minimum width and height.